# Q Lookups TypeError Django

Tags: python, django

In my Car model I have the following fields: `name, manufacturer, body, car_type and description`.

I've implemented a search bar but when I search it's complaining:

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

on `Q(car_type__icontains=query)`

Whats the issue here exactly?

```
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    car = car.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=query) |
        Q(manufacturer__icontains=query) |
        Q(body__icontains=query) |
        Q(car_type__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
```

**Models.py**

```
class CarModelBase(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CarType(CarModelBase, SortableModelBase):
    class Meta(CarModelBase.Meta):
        ordering = ['order']
        verbose_name = 'Car Type'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Car Types'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(CarModelBase):
    manufacturer = SortableForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    car_type = SortableForeignKey(CarType)
    body = SortableForeignKey(Body)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 2):

If `car_type` is a foreign key, then you can't do `Q(car_type__icontains=query)`. You need to specify the field on the `CarTyoe` model that you wish to search, for example:

```
Q(car_type__name__icontains=query)
```

Comment: I've upload it!

Comment: Is it not possible to stil filter through the variables?

Comment: As the error says, you cannot use `__icontains` with a foreign key like `car_type`, because the foreign key is just a reference to the related model. You need to choose the field on the `CarType` model that you want to search, e.g. `name`, and include that in your query, e.g. car_type__name__icontains`.